# When do you need aggregate over dependsOn

Tags: sbt

When doing a multiproject build, you can list the projects you depend upon in `dependsOn`, and tasks will run on the dependencies first, so you can depend on their results.

There also is an `aggregate` task that, eh, aggregates subprojects. How does aggregating and depending on subprojects differ, and in what cases should you use `aggregrate` instead of `dependsOn`

Answer (score 3):

The key difference is `aggregate` does not modify *classpath* and does not establish *ordering* between sub-projects. Consider the following multi-project build consisting of `root`, `core` and `util` projects:

```
├── build.sbt
├── core
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   └── target
├── src
│   ├── main
│   └── test
├── target
│   ├── scala-2.13
│   └── streams
└── util
├── src
└── target
```

where

**`core/src/main/scala/example/Core.scala:`**

```
package example

object Core {
  def foo = "Core.foo"
}
```

**`util/src/main/scala/example/Util.scala`**

```
package example

object Util {
  def foo =
    "Util.foo" + Core.foo // note how we depend on source from another project here
}
```

**`src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:`**

```
package example

object Hello extends App {
  println(42)
}
```

Note how `Util.foo` has a classpath dependency on `Core.foo` from `core` project. If we now try to establish "dependency" using `aggregate` like so

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(core, util)
lazy val util = (project in file("util"))
lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
```

and then execute `compile` from `root` project

```
root/compile
```

it will indeed attempt to compile all the aggregated projects however `Util` will fail compilation because it is missing a classpath dependency:

```
sbt:aggregate-vs-dependsOn> root/compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/mario/IdeaProjects/aggregate-vs-dependson/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/mario/IdeaProjects/aggregate-vs-dependson/core/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/mario/IdeaProjects/aggregate-vs-dependson/util/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[error] /Users/mario/IdeaProjects/aggregate-vs-dependson/util/src/main/scala/example/Util.scala:5:18: not found: value Core
[error]     "Util.foo" + Core.foo // note how we depend on source from another project here
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (util / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 13-Oct-2019 12:35:51
```

Another way of seeing this is to execute `show util/dependencyClasspath` which should have `Core` dependency missing from output.

On the other hand, `dependsOn` will modify classpath and establish appropriate ordering between projects

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(core, util)
lazy val util = (project in file("util")).dependsOn(core)
lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
```

Now `root/compile` gives

```
sbt:aggregate-vs-dependsOn> root/compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/mario/IdeaProjects/aggregate-vs-dependson/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/mario/IdeaProjects/aggregate-vs-dependson/core/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/mario/IdeaProjects/aggregate-vs-dependson/util/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 13-Oct-2019 12:40:25
```

and `show util/dependencyClasspath` shows `Core` on the classpath:

```
sbt:aggregate-vs-dependsOn> show util/dependencyClasspath
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario/IdeaProjects/aggregate-vs-dependson/core/target/scala-2.13/classes)
```

Finally, `aggregate` and `dependsOn` are not mutually exclusive, in fact, it is common practice to use both at the same time, often `aggregate` on the `root` all sub-projects to aid building, whilst using `dependsOn` to handcraft particular orderings for particular sub-projects.